# Pointer to int array, passing and using it from another method

Tags: c++

I haven't cemented my learning of C++ arrays and have forgotten how to do this properly. I've done it with char array before but its not working as well for int array.

I declare a new blank int array:

```
int myIntArray[10];
```

So this should be an array of nulls for the moment correct?

Then I assign a pointer to this array:

```
int *pMyArray = myIntArray
```

Hopefully thats correct to there.

Then I pass this to another method elsewhere:

```
anotherMethod(pMyArray)
```

where I want to assign this pointer to a local variable (this is where I'm really not sure):

```
anotherMethod(int *pMyArray){    
    int myLocalArray[];    
    myLocalArray[0] = *pMyArray;    
}
```

I'm not getting any compilation errors but I'm not sure this is right on a few fronts. Any and all help and advice appreciated with this.

Edit:

I should have said what I am trying to do.

Very simple really, I'd just like to modify a local array from another method.

So I have:

Method 1 would contain:

int myArray1[10] = {0};

Method 2 would be passed the pointer to myArray:

Then some code to modify the variables in the array myArray.

Comment: Using a `std::vector<int>` instead would solve all your problems.

Comment: Some test code could help you figure it out. Don't rely on "knowlege". Test it!

Comment: If you're not getting compilation errors for this program, then you should turn them on. In GCC, that's `g++ -Wall`. Or, even better, `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: `-Wall` isn't really "all", you should use `-Wall -Wextra` (but not any idiotic option like `-pedantic`, hell no!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int myIntArray[10];
```

This is an uninitialized array. It doesn't necessarily contain `0`'s.

```
int *pMyArray = myIntArray
```

Okay, `pMyArray` points to the first element in `myIntArray`.

```
anotherMethod(int *pMyArray){    
    int myLocalArray[10];    
    myLocalArray[0] = *pMyArray;    
}
```

This doesn't assign your pointer to anything, it assigns the first value of the local array to the `int` pointed to by `pMyArray`, which, remember, was uninitialized. I added the `10` there because you can't have an array of unknown size in C++.

To modify what `pMyArray` points to, you need to pass it by reference:

```
anotherMethod(int *& pMyArray)
```

Also, if you assign it to some values in automatic storage, it will result in **undefined behavior**, as that memory is no longer valid when the function exits.

Answer (score 1):

```
int myIntArray[10];
```

**So this should be an array of nulls for the moment correct?**

No, this is an array of `10` integers containing values depending on the storage specification.
If created locally, it has random garbage values.
If created globally it is value initialized which is zero initialized for POD.

Besides that your method just assigns the local array with the first vale of the array you pass.
What are you trying to do exactly? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int myIntArray[10];
> So this should be an array of nulls for the moment correct?
> ```

Not correct, it is an array of 10 uninitialized ints.

> ```
> int *pMyArray = myIntArray
> Hopefully thats correct to there.
> ```

Not quite correct, pMyArray is a pointer to the 1st element, myIntArray[0].

> where I want to assign this pointer to a local variable (this is where
>   I'm really not sure):

If you really need to assign the pointer, you have to use this code

```
int *p_myLocalArray;    
p_myLocalArray = pMyArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes here.

First, array of zeros (not nulls) is achieved by using the initializer syntax:

`int myIntArray[10] = {0};`

Second, `int myLocalArray[];` has a size of 0. And even if it did have a size of, say, 10, writing `myLocalArray[0] = *pMyArray;` will assign the first int from `pMyArray` into `mLocalArray`, which is not what you meant.

If you want to assign a pointer of the array, then simply:

```
int *myLocalPointer;
myLocalPointer = pMyArray;
```

If you want a local copy of the array, you will need to copy it locally, and for that you also need the size and dynamic allocation:

```
void anotherMethod(int *pMyArray, int size){    
    int *myLocalArray = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(myLocalArray, pMyArray, size * sizeof(int));

    ...
    free(myLocalArray);
}
```