# Pointer arithmetic to change array values

Tags: c++

This is a follow on question to an earlier one.

I have learned some errors of my ways, but have extra questions. My objective is to have a local array in one method changed from another method without the use of any global variables.

```
void methodOne(){

        int myArray[10] = {0};
        int *pMyArray = myArray;
        
        methodTwo(&*pMyArray);
}
```

This should be declaring an array of null values and passing a reference to the second array as I was shown how to do so correctly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283200/pointer-to-int-array-passing-and-using-it-from-another-method/10283358#10283358).

```
void methodTwo(int *passedPointer){
       
        int *localPointer =  passedPointer;

}
```

Next I'd like to change the values of myArray from methodTwo. So to change the first `[0]` element I would say:

```
*localPointer  = 1;
```

Is this correct?

Then to change the next element would I increment the pointer using:

```
localPoint++;
*localPointer = 2;
```

Would this change the second value in myArray? I'm not sure thats the correct way to do it is it?

TIA

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Just access with `localPointer[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this all looks like it should work. Generally when you're passing an array to a function, you don't assign to a local variable first though -- you just pass the name of the array as the parameter: `methoTwo(myArray);`. The compiler will automatically convert the name of the array to a pointer to the beginning of the array.

Also note that you can use array-style notation on the receiving end, something like:

```
localpointer[0] = 1;
localpointer[1] = 2;
```

...is also reasonable and will accomplish the same as your

```
*localpointer = 1;
++localpointer;
*localpointer = 2;
```

For what it's worth, another alternative would be:

```
*localpointer++ = 1;
*localpointer = 2;
```

Comment: I never knew you could use the pointer with array notation. That makes it much easier. Ty.

Comment: @EricBanderhide: Yup -- C says that `*(pointer+offset)` is equivalent to `pointer[offset]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you pass the array incorrectly. An array is nothing more than a pointer to the first, element, so you don't need to take it's address to pass it to `MethodTwo`. However, what you should do, is pass in the number of elements in that array to `MehtodTwo`:

```
 methodTwo(MyArray, 10);
```

Since an array is nothing other than a pointer to the first element, you can directly index into the array without requiring the use of pointer arithmetics:

```
void methodTwo(int passedArray[], size_t n)
// alternative void methodTwo(int *passedArray, size_t n)
{

  passedArray[0] =  passedPointer;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is wrong. Very wrong. Array to pointer decay is really, really bad and you should never, ever, use it. Use a class-based wrapper like `std::array`, and pass in a pair of iterators to MethodTwo.